# How to delete the last div of a scrollable div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have created a custom scrollable div as follows:

```
    <!-- Chat box content area Start -->
    <div class="row" id="ChatboxContentBlock">
                <div class="scrollContent">

                    <!-- chat messages start -->

                    <div class="row replyMessageRow">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 replyThumbnail">
                            <img src="/images/botimg.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 replyContentBlock">
                            <div class="replyContent">
                                <p>How are you?</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 replyLastCol">

                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row sendMessageRow">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 sendingLastCol">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 sendingContentBlock">
                            <div class="sendingContent">
                                <p>new content ok. Yeah, I agree.</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 sendingThumbnail">
                            <img src="/images/sam.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row replyMessageRow">
                            <div class="col-sm-2 replyThumbnail">
                                <img src="/images/botimg.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 replyContentBlock">
                                <div class="replyContent">
                                    <p>How are you? Yeah, just answering my own question. How is the world now a days? is it yet a better place? I hope so. Yeah, this is just a dummy paragraph.</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 replyLastCol">

                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row sendMessageRow">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 sendingLastCol">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 sendingContentBlock">
                            <div class="sendingContent">
                                <p>new content ok. Yeah, I agree.</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 sendingThumbnail">
                            <img src="/images/sam.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row replyMessageRow">
                            <div class="col-sm-2 replyThumbnail">
                                <img src="/images/botimg.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 replyContentBlock">
                                <div class="replyContent">
                                    <p>How are you?</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 replyLastCol">

                            </div>
                    </div>



                    <!-- chat messages end -->

                </div>



    </div>
    <!-- Chat box content area End -->
```

Here each `div` of class `replyMessageRow` or `sendMessageRow` is a scrollable item.

I want to delete the last element of `div` with class `scrollContent`.

Currently, I am trying to achieve this with the below code:

```
$('.scrollContent:last-child').remove();
```

But this probably removes the entire `.scrollContent` div and because of which I see only a big white screen in the chat window with nothing in it.

What is the correct way to delete the last element of a div?

Answer (score 0):

You were removing the last element whose class was `scrollContent`. Rather you want to find the last element inside the `scrollContent` element and remove it.

This line of code does the job very well:

```
$('.scrollContent').children(':last-child').remove();
```